# Springboot Multi-tenant with MultiTenantConnectionProvider always throw org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I have started converted my exiting Spring Boot(1.5.4.RELEASE) application to work with multi-tenant features.it is a schema based multi-tenant solution and based on mysql.
As hibernate document suggested below

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

i have implemented both MultiTenantConnectionProvider and CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver interfaces and it works fine.

```
package com.ifi.aws.tenant.config.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ifi.aws.tenant.entity.TenantContext;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6246085840652870138L;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
  return dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
  connection.close();
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
  final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
  try {
    connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + tenantIdentifier );
  }
  catch ( SQLException e ) {
    throw new HibernateException(
        "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
      e
      );
  }
  return connection;
}

@Override
public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
  try {
    connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT );
  }
  catch ( SQLException e ) {
    throw new HibernateException(
        "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
      e
      );
  }
  connection.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
  return false;
}

@Override
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
  return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
  return true;
}

}
```

---

```
package com.ifi.aws.tenant.config.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.ifi.aws.tenant.entity.TenantContext;

@Configuration
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

  @Override
  public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {


     String tenantId = TenantContext.getTenantSchema();

    //System.out.println("------------------ resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier = " + tenantId);
    if (tenantId != null) {
        return tenantId;
    }
    return TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT;
}
@Override
public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
}
}
```

and then below is my hibernate configuration

```
package com.ifi.aws.tenant.config.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.MultiTenancyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

  @Autowired
  private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
  MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
  CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.putAll(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource));
    properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
    properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
    properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.ifi.aws");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
   return em;
  }
}
```

however time to time system crashes with below error

```
Springboot Multi-tenant with MultiTenantConnectionProvider always throw org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [http-nio-8086-exec-2] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
```

i Did some reading on this site and found exact same issue in below questions.

[Spring Boot: Apache derby pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647962/spring-boot-apache-derby-pool-empty-unable-to-fetch-a-connection-in-30-seconds)
[Tomcat Connection Pool Exhasuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368032/tomcat-connection-pool-exhasuted)

One of the fixes they suggested was to to add below configurations

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
```

But still i am getting the same error and i debug the code and found that it closes the connection after each execution of the database call. Do you guys have any idea?

### Edit

Yesterday i found that the API does not close any connection at all. I wrote a simple utility to the check the connection status as below

```
    @Autowired
private DataSource ds;

@Before("execution(* com.ifi.aws.*.dao.impl.springData.*.*(..))")
public void logBeforeConnection(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    logDataSourceInfos("Before", jp);
}

@After("execution(* com.ifi.aws.*.dao.impl.springData.*.*(..)) ")
public void logAfterConnection(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    logDataSourceInfos("After", jp);
}

public void logDataSourceInfos(final String time, final JoinPoint jp) {
    final String method = String.format("%s:%s", jp.getTarget().getClass().getName(), jp.getSignature().getName());
    logger.debug("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    logger.debug(String.format("%s %s: number of connections in use by the application (active): %d.", time, method, ds.getNumActive()));
    logger.debug(String.format("%s %s: the number of established but idle connections: %d.", time, method, ds.getNumIdle()));
    logger.debug(String.format("%s %s: number of threads waiting for a connection: %d.", time, method, ds.getWaitCount()));
}
```

}

The out of this shows continuous growth of active connections.

```
Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of connections in use by the application (active): 21.
Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: the number of established but idle connections: 0.
Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of threads waiting for a connection: 0

-----------------

After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of connections in use by the application (active): 21.
After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: the number of established but idle connections: 0.
After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of threads waiting for a connection: 0.
o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl                : committing

-------------------

Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of connections in use by the application (active): 21.
Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: the number of established but idle connections: 0.
Before com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of threads waiting for a connection: 0

-----------------

After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of connections in use by the application (active): 22.
After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: the number of established but idle connections: 0.
After com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127:findOne: number of threads waiting for a connection: 0.
o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl                : committing

-------------------
```

However it perfectly fine in my local environment and it properly closes the connections. My Testing environment deployed in AWS t2 windows instance this API is deployed as a Spring Boot jar file with a MYSQL server installed with in the same t2 instance. The only difference i can see is the OPeration system version and may be some MYSQL server configurations

**Edit**

I was able to fix the issue by following the instructions by @xerx593

the issue was with supportsAggressiveRelease = true  and i changed it false as suggested @xerx593. However im still wondering how come it works in my local environment and not in the testing environment. According to the hibernate doc it says "Does this connection provider support aggressive release of JDBC connections and re-acquistion of those connections (if need be) later?". Both the test and local environments have the same configurations and can it be a result of version of operation system or mysql cofiguration?

Thanks,
Kelum

Comment: `MultiTenantConnectionProvider ` is maybe who throws (he sits fright at the front door), but the connection leak could be anywhere... or it is no connection leak, but your app is really high frequented. (have you tried `max-active=1000`?) ..and what means "time to time"..?

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for your reply. Time to time means while i was doing the testing it got crashed but i couldn't see any pattern. But Yesterday i found that it does not close any connection at all. If we do max-active=1000, it will crash after 1000 database calls. I did a small utility to check the connections and this api properly close connections in my Local environment but in the staging environment which is on AWS t2 micto windows instance it does not close any connection at all. Please note that the MYSQL server also installed locally in that t2 instance. updated the above description

Comment: ... so (for me) only remains random guessing: 1. Is DEFAULT_TENANT  on the db (of concern)? 2. "Try to" encapsulate the `connection.close()` into `finally` block (MTPImpl) 3. "try" `supportsAggressiveRelease = false`

Comment: @xerx593, it worked thanks. the issue was with supportsAggressiveRelease = true and i changed it false as you suggested. However im still wondering how come it works in my local environment and not in the testing environment. According to the hibernate doc it says "Does this connection provider support aggressive release of JDBC connections and re-acquistion of those connections (if need be) later?". Both the test and local environments have the same configurations and can it be a result of version of operation system or mysql cofiguration?

Comment: but i had to "guess" it 3. (of 3), huh!? -> Murphy's law!?  :)  Glad, we "fixed" it ... but to really "understand" (the difference in your environments), we need more info/you have to compare! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "brute force", we found the problem was in the `supportsAggressiveRelease` flag, which when set (`= true`), showed no issues in DEV environment, but lead to problems on your AWS instance(s).

#### Solution:

```
@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
   return false;//!
}
```

---

Why this environment not supports "aggressive release", is in the configuration/nature of your environment...

- [MultiTenantConnectionProvider javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html)
- [AWS Documentation main page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/index.html)